# Which test can I use for this science related project?

Tags: anova, t-test

I’m currently doing a science project on sickle cell disease, I’m researching to see how a well a few drugs can induce fetal haemoglobin in sickle cell disease patients.

Currently what I’ve done is gather results from clinical studies, in which I took the mean levels of fetal haemoglobin in all patients before the trial and the means of the level of fetal haemoglobin after the trial. I then put the numbers in a T test to calculate the efficiency of the drug to induce fetal haemoglobin. Is this correct?

If not how can I go about this? And what test can I use, id appreciate all your help. Thank you

Comment: Seems a more direct approach would be a paired t test with (before, after) scores for each patient.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform a "meta-analysis," which is particularly suited for dealing with means or odds ratios from multiple studies.  There should be some good R-Project packages on meta-analysis, or perhaps in the software you are using.